# Where to use an rvalue as a function parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14, rvalue

I know there are plenty of questions about the argument, but I still don't understand some basic stuff about rvalues.

Supposing I have a function of this kind:

```
/* 1 */ void func( std::string s ) { /* do something with s */ }
```

which I use in this way:

```
int main()
{
  func( "a string" );
}
```

In a case like that, in which I pass this string to the function `func` wouldn't be better to always define this kind of function in this way:

```
/* 2 */ void func( std::string&& s ) { /* do something with s */ }
```

My question is: wouldn't be always better to use `/* 2 */` instead of `/* 1 */` in cases like the one of this example? And if not, why and where should I use the one or the other? The fact is that, if I understood well, in `/* 2 */` the parameter is moved and will never be used outside of the function scope, right?

Comment: what is "a case like that" ?

Comment: The problem with #2 is you can't do `func(lvalue_string_object)` anymore, where #1 allows that.  My advice, only use an rvalue reference parameter when you want to explicitly transfer the object from the calling scope into the callie scope.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I meant like the one of the example I posted

Comment: @NathanOliver what do you mean with "callie" scope?

Comment: I don't get whats special about it, its a function like any other. Are you asking if you should make all function arguments rvalue references?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number exaclty

Comment: see here https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-conventional

Comment: @GianlucaBianco Yes.  Comment has been edited.

Comment: It depends what you're going to do with the argument

Comment: you would only make a copy (as in `void func( std::string s )`) when you need a copy. Maybe the better comparison would be with `void func(const std::string& s)`

Comment: Your example code may not be the best to illustrate _"Where to use an rvalue?"_   You are promising to only pass a temporary and asking if the function should insist on a temporary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific example where a temporary string is created at call time, both expressions are equivalent.

Indeed, you could not keep both and use overload resolution, because they capture the same type of object (again, only in your example). They both can capture the temporary string and have it available in parameter `s`.